# Restrict Access in Admin Panel

Tags: user-roles, security, user-access

I want to restrict access to certain plugin pages / normal WP Pages. I've found a way to Hide these pages from the menu but currently not restrict them. For instance, I have an editor and I don't want them to have access to `Media` and `Tools` - I can hide those pages via this:

```
function editor_menu() {
    global $menu;

    if(!current_user_can('administrator'))
    {
        $restricted = array(__('Media'),__('Tools'));
        end ($menu);
        while (prev($menu)){
            $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
            if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted)){unset($menu[key($menu)]);}
        }
    }
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'editor_menu', 999);
```

But how can I restrict them from viewing this page entirely? Like permissions?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct solution here is to just update the $capability component of the admin_menu items rather than just remove them from the menu structure.

Try this:

```
/** Set 'administrator' cap for particular menu items **/
function update_admin_menu() {
    global $menu, $submenu;

    $menu[10][1] = 'administrator'; // Media
    foreach( $submenu['upload.php'] as &$item ) {
        $item[1] = 'administrator';
    }

    $menu[75][1] = 'administrator'; // Tools
    foreach( $submenu['tools.php'] as &$item ) {
        $item[1] = 'administrator';
    }    
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'update_admin_menu', 1000 );
```

Please note that checking against [user levels](http://codex.wordpress.org/User_Levels) is deprecated, but it works in this situation and is essentially the same as it would be if you created a new cap (which administrators would automatically have access to,) and assigning that capability to these menu items instead.

Comment: Where part is checking against user levels? `$item[1]`?

Comment: Yeah, capabilities are stored at index 1 in each of these arrays.

Answer (score -2):

Best bet is to use a plugin such as [User Roles Pro](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) which does what you need, you can create new user roles and then restrict them from doing xx tasks in the admin.

Comment: This plugin's great, but I don't think it offers the granularity needed to do what OP requests. For example, access to the "Media" menu item is controlled by the `upload_files` capability, but disabling that for editors will also prevent them from using the media manager to add images to a post. Likewise, `tools` is hooked on the `edit_posts` capability, which is definitely required for an editor role.

Comment: @GarethGillman I'm not the biggest fan of plugins. I also think that plugin suggestions shouldn't be considered "answers" as much as "comments". I'd personally like to learn how to create and edit roles myself for the long run. Thanks though!